# How can I limit the winston log files to a specific number

Tags: node.js, winston

I am thinking of using the log rotation feature of Winston. Is there any way to limit the number of log files. For example if I am rotating files daily, is there a way to specify I want to keep only logs for last three days ?

Comment: *`maxFiles`: Limit the number of files created when the size of the logfile is exceeded.*

Comment: That's great, reading thru the doc now :) thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments - @Aleksandr M

**maxFiles** is that property.

It could read like this:

```
dailyRotateFile: {
    colorize: false,
    timestamp: true,
    datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm',
    filename: filename,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxsize: 100000000,
    json: false
}
```