# How to delete files from winston log after certain days limit?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using winston to log files into server that is working as expected , now i want to set days limit , Lets say after 3 days i want to delete files that are logged 3 days ago , is it possible to achieve using winston rotation ?

main.js

```
 winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
        filename: './Logs/server.log',
        maxsize:'15000',
        timestamp:false
    });
```

Comment: do you know please share answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit the winston log files to a specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214308/how-can-i-limit-the-winston-log-files-to-a-specific-number)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Winston daily rotate](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file) for this.

Short answer: Yes, you can do that by adding `maxFiles:3d` in `transport` option.

- If you do not set the `maxFiles`, no log file will be deleted.
- If you set `maxFiles:3d`, it will delete all log files created in the last 3 days.
- If you set `maxFiles:3`, it will delete log files when it exceeds more than 3.

Note: You can archive files before deleting by using `zippedArchive: true`, if not set the logs files will be deleted without any backup. Till now, I didn't get any way to auto-delete zip files.

Sample setup:

````
  require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

  var transport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d'
  });

  transport.on('rotate', function(oldFilename, newFilename) {
    // do something fun
  });

  var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      transport
    ]
  });

  logger.info('Hello World!');```
````

Comment: Just to clarify `maxFiles:3d` will delete the files which are generated in last 3 days and not files that are older than 3d ? if yes, is there a way to delete files older than certain days?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a couple of hours trying to understand how log rotation should work. At least version 3.10.0 of winston-daily-rotate-file is using file-stream-rotator to do file rotation. I found the following options to work:

```
    const options = (level: string) => ({
      name: `${level}-log`,
      filename: `${APP_NAME}.${level}.%DATE%.log`,
      dirname: CONFIG.logDir,
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      maxFiles: '1d',
      auditFile: `${CONFIG.logDir}/${APP_NAME}.${level}-audit.json`,
      level,
    })

    new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile(options('error'))
```

This makes Winston to create audit.json file per application and logging level. If you don't specify auditFile option, you end up with generated audit file name, which consists of hash value of options, which will change whenever you change options. If you change options, your audit file name changes and Winston is unable to delete files prior to options change.

In my opinion, the use of audit file is not a good approach. It would have been better to parse timestamps from log file names without any extra file. For example, you cannot add log rotation to an existing application and let Winston to delete log files created prior to configuring Winston log rotation.